# How can I check network type in java?(using IP address)

Tags: java, ip

help me please.
I found in android. => ConnectivityManager 
but It is not my anwser T.T

How can I check network type(WiFi or 3G in java?(using IP address)?

Comment: in java means in android/j2me?

Comment: thx SiknePike in java means j2me

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the plataform, in nokia you can try this:

String value = System.getProperty("com.nokia.network.access");

The possible return values are:

```
• pd - Packet data in GSM network 
• pd.EDGE - Packet data in EDGE network 
• pd.3G - Packet data in 3G network 
• pd.HSDPA - High speed downlink packet access for 3G networks 
• csd - Circuit switched data, for example GSM CSD/HSCSD data call 
• bt_pan - Bluetooth PAN network 
• wlan - Wireless network, for example 802.11b, 802.11G or WiMaX 
• ‘na’ Not applicable, the implementation can’t determine the type
```

Source: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/TSJ000306_-_MIDP:_System_properties